# Sharepoint workflow sending email to Sharepoint Group defined in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

For context: My team has a SharePoint (sub)site which contains an InfoPath path that appends to a SharePoint List. One of the fields in this form is a SharePoint Group (hidden), so that once a user submits this form, the List contains a reference to the relevant SharePoint Group. **All of this is working as intended.**

We've also set up a simple workflow that emails the SharePoint Group mentioned above when a new entry is added to the List. This is not working any longer. This functionality was working about 2 months ago, but now for some reason when it gets triggered it goes to a status of 'Started', and then finally goes to a status of 'Suspended'. See below for more details on the Started and Suspended statuses.

When I setup the workflow to email a static person, it works fine.

**Here is the config for the email message in the workflow:**

- Data source: Current Item
- Field from source: [SharePoint Group field]
- Return field as: Email Address

**Some other notes:**

- The Group is set up on the parent sharepoint and has read access to both the parent and the child.
- The Group is visible by everyone

**Details about Status:**

Started:

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to https://sharepointsite.com/site/subsite/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.ResolvePrincipalInCurrentcontext(input=@ParamUser,scopes='15',sources='15',inputIsEmailOnly='false',addToUserInfoList='True')?%40ParamUser='SD&I+Service+Focal(s)' Correlation Id: c9706d34-5654-3916-bdde-3ae4147b18cf Instance Id: 9b57de3d-d115-4a79-b2e5-e2a9239e8709
```

Suspended:

```
RequestorId: c9706d34-5654-3916-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400 {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The query string \"input\" is missing or invalid."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["7"],"SPRequestGuid":["c9706d34-5654-3916-bbfd-0b7313f83918"],"request-id":["c9706d34-5654-3916-bbfd-0b7313f83918"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4737"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon, 10 Oct 2016 16:03:57 GMT"],"Set-Cookie":["BIGipServerwcms-ew-80-pool=3893922185.20480.0000; path=\/"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS\/8.0"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine`1.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in my particular case is that the SharePoint group name had an ampersand in the name. SharePoint didn't bother to encode it during an api call. I've also read elsewhere that an apostrophe can cause this error.